# MYSQL django test error: django.db.utils.InternalError: (7, "Error on rename of

Tags: mysql, django, django-testing, mysql-5.7, django-tests

I am running a django 1.9.6 app with MYSQL5.7 on IIS 8.5

When i run the python manage.py test command I get the following error message:

***django.db.utils.InternalError: (7, "Error on rename of '.\test_\#sql-95c_9a.frm' to '.\test_\home_mytable.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)")***

did test with -v 3 and it throws this error when running the migration files (not always on the same one).

I have granted necessary permissions on this folder C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data

any pointers on how to solve this error? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Mcafee Anitvirus caused this issue by preventing the frm files to be modified. Solved by disabling on-access scan in MCaFee Threat Prevention Advanced Option and setting Mcafee to ignore these frm extensions.
[image of MCaFee interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4iKP.jpg)

Comment: Same here. Took more than a day to find out the cause but this post helped a lot. Issues always came on ALTER TABLE statements so my solution was to do a dump that have no ALTER TABLEs in it (or much less) than the liquibase script that did set up the db for tests.